# Alternative for order by DESC

Tags: sql, performance, sql-order-by, where-clause

It takes total 9mins for this sql query to fetch records..

```
select top 1 checkdate 
from BTHI1
where CUSTOMERID = 'AUTOMO' and recordtype='T'
order by checkdate desc
```

any other way it can reduced the query time?

Comment: If you run this in SSMS (I'm assuming SQL Server based on `top`, but you really ought to add a specific tag, as the [tag:sql] tag says), does it give any messages about missing indexes? You can also, using the same tool generate an execution plan to see how the system is optimising the query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It does not give any missing indexes error. it finely generated the result. but I want to lower the exec time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select top 1 checkdate 
from BTHI1
where CUSTOMERID = 'AUTOMO' and recordtype = 'T'
order by checkdate desc
```

You want an index on `BTH1(CUSTOMERID, recordtype, checkdate DESC)`.  The first two columns can be in either order.

Note that you can also write this as:

```
select max(checkdate) 
from BTHI1
where CUSTOMERID = 'AUTOMO' and recordtype = 'T';
```